# JQuery and Select Row / Mouseover

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css

I added jQuery to my App o freeze columns and rows. And it works as long I don't need auto select, mouseover CSS and sorting function.

Unfortunality now I can't select rows and sort the table anymore. And it seems that the table is cut in two see screenshot:

[image]

**Edit**:

I solved the selected row problem but *

> freezesize: 14*

gives me a white gap in the grid, why?

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the Grid had a few columns that I hide with:

```
GridView1.Columns[11].Visible = false; 
GridView1.Columns[12].Visible = false;
```

jQuery shows the columns but without text...